# Get dialog window handler

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have MFC dialog based window application. Main dialog form creation is shown in code below. I have some code that runs on separate thread and sometimes I need to send message to dialog window. For this I need window handler.

Line MyAppDlg.GetSafeHwnd() returns 0. Why ? How to get dialog window handler?

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    // Activate "Windows Native" visual manager for enabling themes in MFC controls
    CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerWindows));

    startAll(NULL);             

    CMyAppDlg MyAppDlg;         

    m_pMainWnd = &MyAppDlg;
    m_pActiveWnd = &MyAppDlg;

    AuthMsgHWND = MyAppDlg.GetSafeHwnd();       

    INT_PTR nResponse = MyAppDlg.DoModal();

    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with OK
    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with Cancel
    }
    else if (nResponse == -1)
    {
        TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: dialog creation failed, so application is terminating unexpectedly.\n");
        TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: if you are using MFC controls on the dialog, you cannot #define _AFX_NO_MFC_CONTROLS_IN_DIALOGS.\n");
    }

    // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
    //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
    return FALSE;       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog object has been created but the dialog window (and its HWND) are not created until after DoModal is called.  The first place you can get access to this HWND is in the dialog's OnInitDialog function.

Answer (score 1):

You've tried to get the `HWND` of the object before the dialog has been created with `DoModal` - that won't work. And since `DoModal` won't return until the dialog has been destroyed, you can't do it after. You'll have to find another point where you can capture that handle.

P.S. Don't call `SendMessage` from another thread. You're asking for trouble. Use `PostMessage` instead.